# How to get file in a library iOS

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, nsbundle, getfiles, ios-library

I am trying to construct a library in IOS.

In my library ,I use a method -(void)loadNewData  to load some data EX:**test.csv**.

But when I export my library and let the other app use my library to excute the loadNewData method.
I found it can not be load correctly. It seems that because there is not such a file **test.csv** in the app.

How should I revise my code? Or where should I notice when I export the library?

Thank you for watch my question.
And sorry for my poor English.

Here is the a part of code of the loadNewData:

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *Rawsurveys=[resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.csv"];
NSString *RawsurveyResults;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:Rawsurveys])
    {
        NSLog(@"find file");
        NSFileHandle *RawfileHandle=[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:Rawsurveys];
        RawsurveyResults=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[RawfileHandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [RawfileHandle closeFile];

    }
```

Comment: Where you have kept in "test.csv" file

Comment: I just add the test.csv in Build Phases/Copy files from my desktop.

Comment: I have tested if I also add the test.csv in the other app then the code works.However,I don't want to let the app know my test.csv.

Comment: If `test.csv` contains some private data, why not encrypt it ? Then provide the encrypted file to users who use your library.

Comment: @KudoCC thank you for your advice.But  I want to implement my idea first :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably create a bundle within your library and add you `test.csv` there.
Then you can access your `test.csv` from your own bundle.

Example of how I use images from my bundle. `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myBundle.bundle/myImage"]`. You could use the somewhat same for your file

Comment: Sorry,I can't understand what you mean. How to access my own bundle ? Can you give me some example code here? I will appreciate your help. :)

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager , check how there is a separate bundle for images made here and how how these images are accesses by the framework

Comment: oh ya!! I just google "How to create a bundle" and study some documents there. Now I totally understand what you mean then I follow your steps and  it works perfectly. Thank you for your help again :) .